# Python - How to get the product of list inside a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to multiply all the numbers together in a list that is inside a list

For example:

```
l1 = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

to my desired output:

```
[2,3,6]
```

I have tried using

```
l2 = functools.reduce(lambda x , y: x * y , l1)
```

but what I got was this error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

can anyone please help me? I'm just a rookie

Comment: `reduce` is not a proper function for this task. Read the doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: You should use a list comprehension: `l2 = [functools.reduce(lambda x , y: x * y , l) for l in l1]`